# Why must we change = to # when working with ps2pdf in Windows?

Tags: windows, ps2pdf

1. Which is the correct syntax for `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` passed to `ps2pdf` in Windows?

   ```
   ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None input.ps output.pdf
   ```

   or

   ```
   ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages#/None input.ps output.pdf
   ```

   ?
2. Why is there a slash in `/None`?
3. And why cannot we use `=` in Windows?

Comment: Isn't this parameter not simply passed to Ghostscript? So you would have to look for the correct syntax of Ghostscript. The slash comes from the PostScript syntax I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Windows

```
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages#/None input.ps output.pdf
```

pdf is a subset of PostScript where functions are defined as `/<name>`

Comment: no idea, I am a Linux user, which makes live easier ... :-)

Comment: life is live ... :-)

Comment: It should be "which makes for an easier life". You can't use "live", which is a verb, in that context.

Comment: @xport: Please don't. It is "makes life easier" of course as any dictionary will tell you. It's a common error made by Germans.

Comment: @ Martin: I know, it was a joke ...

Comment: The `=` is used in batch files as delimiter to separate arguments (like space or tab). See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/35938/en-us.

Comment: @Ulrike: Thanks. Another funny limitation of Windows. It e.g. also can't create files which are named like interfaces: `com1.tex` isn't valid. Nor `dsp.c` (a Linux audio driver file I friend wanted to unzip under Windows once)

Comment: @Herbert: I knew you knew it, but xport apparently didn't got it. I really didn't liked to have a link at english.sx pointing here. :-|

Comment: Now `ps2pdf` is a `.exe` console application (implemented as `ps2pdf.tlu` Lua script) in TeX Live. Thus the problem is solved. There are still problematic `ps2pdf.bat` and `ps2pdf.cmd` distributed with GhostScript.

Comment: @Martin: Such limitations are not solely on windows. E.g. TeX-users trying their first pstricks code should better not name their document pstricks.tex.

Comment: @Ulrike: Oh, yeah, I remember doing such a mistake once! :-D

Answer (score 2):

1. `ps2pdf` is a batch file.
2. In MS-Windows, batch file uses `=` as a dilimiter as discussed in the link given by Ulrike. I copied and pasted here for the sake of convenience.

   > Using batch files in MS-DOS, it is not possible to include an equal
   >   sign as an argument to a batch file. The batch file parser considers
   >   this to be a delimiter, such as a space or tab character. Thus, using
   >   the following one-line batch file (named TEST.BAT):
   >
   > ```
   > echo %1 %2
   > ```
   >
   > If the following is entered:
   >
   > ```
   > TEST one=two
   > ```
   >
   > it would produce the following output
   >
   > ```
   > one two
   > ```
   >
   > which shows that the batch file parser considers "one" the first
   >   argument, and "two" the second argument, with the equal sign being a
   >   delimiter. This makes it impossible to enter equal signs in batch
   >   files as command-line options.
3. But don't get confused with `latex -interaction=nonstopmode` which uses `=` here. `latex` is not a batch file. Period! This is a confusion that I had just experienced. :-)